# Yii2 Modules in advanced template

Tags: php, module, yii2

I want to create a module (for example Users) in an advanced template application, that I could use it both in the backend (CRUD functionality) and frontend (login, profile)

Which is the right way of doing it, without having to create one module in backend and another in frontend and maybe a model in the common folder?

I want all files in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for for create a module that you can use both backend and frontend and easily reusable also in other project is create the module in a your vendor dir eg:

```
  vendor\yourvendorname\modulename\Module.php
```

then create the  necessary dir

```
   vendor\yourvendorname\modulename\controllers
   vendor\yourvendorname\modulename\models
   vendor\yourvendorname\modulename\views
```

the module name in module section config\main.php

```
'modules' => [  

 ...

     'modulename' => [ // dfenx module for migration via web without console command
        'class' => 'vendor\youvendorname\yourmodulename\Module',
    ],
```

then refer to the module in you url eg:

```
  yourprojectname/backend/web/index.php/modulename/controller
```

you can refer to this [guide for tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)

Comment: so how do I recognize backend controllers from frontend controller, should I create `vendor\yourvendorname\modulenameBackend\controllers` and `vendor\yourvendorname\modulenameFrontend\controllers`?

Comment: Normally the module is created for give at both the app the action you need. Is a common part of function for an organic set of functionality. If  you need different behaviour form the module controller  in backend or frontend you can extend the base (module) controller and redefine you action/fnction